# using newaxis() function in python

Tags: python

I am not clear what following  python code is doing:

```
def decode_netout(netout, anchors, obj_thresh, net_h, net_w):
    grid_h, grid_w = netout.shape[:2]
    nb_box = 3
    netout = netout.reshape((grid_h, grid_w, nb_box, -1))
    nb_class = netout.shape[-1] - 5
    boxes = []
    netout[..., :2]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., :2])
    netout[..., 4:]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., 4:])
    netout[..., 5:]  = netout[..., 4][..., np.newaxis] * netout[..., 5:]
    netout[..., 5:] *= netout[..., 5:] > obj_thresh
```

I am not clear about following line of above code snippet:

```
'netout[..., 5:]  = netout[..., 4][..., np.newaxis] * netout[..., 5:]'
```

Here netout is is array with [13, 13, 3, 85] dimensions. In that case, what is above statement functionality?

thanks and regards,
-sunil puranik

Comment: What are all those objects exactly…?! That'll determine what that does…

Comment: netout  is an array with shape of 13, 13, 3, 85.  net_h and net_w each have value of 416 (size of image). obj_thresh is a constant with value of 0.6. sigmoid is the sigmoid function 1/(1+ exp(-x)) in machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

In this the newaxis command is used to have an axis with dimension 1 at the end. Without this axis, the broadcasting in the multiplication with `netout[..., 5:]` would not work. This would be an equivalent statement:

```py
netout[..., 5:]  = netout[..., 4:5] * netout[..., 5:]
```

If an axis of a numpy array is indexed with an integer numpy will drop the axis, if it is indexed with a slice of length 1, the axis with dimension 1 is kept.